# Using token concetenation in a #define

Tags: c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, preprocessor-directive

Is there an alternative to using the preprocessor concatenation operator `##` in a `#define` as follows

```
#define EXCLUDE_FROM_INSTANTIATION( Type )   \
    #define SUPPRESS_##Type                  \
    DO_CRAZY_STUFF()                         \
    #undef SUPPRESS_##Type                   \
```

Comment: You cant do that. I don't think there is an alternative.

Comment: Specifically, you can't put preprocessor directives inside a macro definition. They won't be interpreted as directives.

Comment: I'd be tempted to look into `DO_CRAZY_STUFF()` to see if you could rewrite it with a parameter and use `DO_CRAZY_STUFF(SUPPRESS_##Type)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done with the C preprocessor. The most obvious solution, but a bad one, is to run the preprocessor twice. That would involve custom build steps that wouldn't be intuitive to anoyone trying to maintain your code down the line. Generally if you need something like that it makes more sense to move to a more powerful macro processor/code generator. One of the most common free ones is [m4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)).